# How to Bind Data To List View In xamarin Android?

Tags: c#, android, rest, asp.net-web-api, xamarin

I am newbie in xamarin,
i am trying to bind dynamic data (consuming from Web Api)  to listview. but have no idea how to bind data i have made web api for getting data from database

```
    public List<ProductMaster> GetAllProductOfRestaurent(int id)
    {
        return entity.ProductMasters.Where(x => x.RestaurentId == id).ToList();
    }
```

now how to consume webapi for list? and bind it to listview? any code sample?

Comment: If you are using Xamarin.Android there's no direct way you could bind a list to a listview. You must use some 3rd party libraries (`MvvmLight` or `MvvmCross`

Comment: Any Sample Code for both?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using plain xamarin.android you can bind using Adapters as shown in this article.

[Part 2 - Populating a ListView With Data - Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/part_2_-_populating_a_listview_with_data/)

if you want to use a popular MVVM you need to use third party library like MVVMCross. In MVVMCross you will have MVXListView which can be binded to the Collection of Objects, as below

```
<Mvx.MvxListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/mlvMantraas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:divider="@color/primary"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Mantraas;ItemClick MantraSelectedCommand"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/mantraitem" >
    </Mvx.MvxListView>
```